# Textarea maxlength and SQL Server nvarchar does not match with breakline

Tags: sql-server, textarea, line-breaks, maxlength, nvarchar

I set attribute maxlength of textarea as 10 and I set `nvarchar(10)` for a column in a table. I am using SQL Server 2014.

The problem is when I type enter, textarea will count length as 1 but SQL Server count it as 2.

When I type enter 10 times and then I save the textarea value in database, it throws error "truncated".

What should I do in this situation? How can I set maxlength of textarea and set length of nvarchar in database?

Should I modify string in server before saving to database?

Comment: If you type **10 characters** into your textarea, SQL Server will count those as **10 characters** also. Storing it in a `nvarchar` column will use **2 bytes per character** - but that doesn't mean each character from the input is duplicated....

Comment: But for the breakline, textarea count as 1 but sql server count it as 2 for the length. So how can I set maxlength and nvarchar?